# Google Sketchup C++ SDK: SkpWriter usage

Tags: c++, 3d, sketchup

I am trying to use Google's Sketchup C++ SDK (latest version) to export a 3D model to a Sketchup file. One of the problems I am facing is that the header files refer to an ["sapi" folder](http://groups.google.com/group/su-sdk-fileshare/browse_thread/thread/d78c0acf22403a41) which does not exist in the source tree.

I need to figure out how I can get a reference to the ISketchUpApplication interface. Can someone provide me with example code on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [latest SDK](http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/downloadsdksubmit.html) comes with an example showing how the writer is used. The example can be found at "SkpWriter/Examples/skpwriter_example/skpwriter_example" within the Windows SDK download bundle.